# How do I use openssl.exe in bin directory windows plesk?

Tags: ssl, openssl, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, plesk

I Have a site Based on joomdle that It is required to use Openssl of the page.
This site is on the Windows Server 2008 and The control panel is Plesk 9.5 .
in bin directory Plesk exists file Openssl.exe.
How can it be used for my site?